# Как сделать сортировку массива по алфавиту?

Tags: php, массивы

Как сделать сортировку по алфавиту вот такого масива

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 174
                    [title_folder] => Регистрация
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 204
                    [title_folder] => Авто
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 47
                    [title_folder] => Речки
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 48
                    [title_folder] => Автодром
                )

        )
)
```

Пробовал так но результата что то нет.

```
usort($array_folders_marking_abc_info, function($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['0']['title_folder'] , $b['0']['title_folder']);
 });
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/DCFQX5 мне кажется что все прекрасно работает у вас

Comment: Работает: https://repl.it/repls/WrongFrayedListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для PHP 7:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[0]['title_folder'] <=> $b[0]['title_folder'];
});
```

Comment: Работает :) Спасибо за помощ.

Answer (score 0):

А если так?

```
usort($array_folders_marking_abc_info, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['0']['title_folder'] == $b['0']['title_folder']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['0']['title_folder'] < $b['0']['title_folder']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/271459)

Comment: @KostaB. вполне нормальный ответ. это никакое не замечание и тем более не уточнение.

Comment: Подскажите, тогда отличия вашего ответа и `strcmp` функции, которая упоминается в вопросе?

Comment: @KostaB. та никакой, как и у ответа, который понравился автору. Просто другая реализация сравнения строк раз у автора возникли проблемы. Можете теперь и к другим постам придраться (и к лучшему посту). Но стоит отметить, что другая реализация это не замечание и не уточнение. Вопрос я думаю закрыт.